# Application Design / Integration

Tags: database, integration, erp

I have been asked to develop an application which will use data available from our ERP system. This application is required because the ERP does not provide what the business requires.

My question is what approach should I take?

If I was to model the domain of the new application there would be the notion of an employee, however the notion of an employee already exists in the ERP domain, however it does not have all the data that is needed by the new application. Should I create a seperate model for the new system regardless of the ERP and then somehow integrate these 2 solutions?

or

Should my new application just model the missing bits and get data from the ERP system via a web service and then combine them to complete my view of an employee?

Comment: Why re-invent parts that ERP is already covering? Sounds like you just need to augment the ERP system, not re-make it. You're basically adding fields to the `employee` table, right? Just create an aux table to hold the added fields and key it the same as the `employee` table in ERP.

Comment: @JonathanM That answers first part of question and is what I expected, on the second part should I model it all within my new system or build a web service over the top of ERP which would allow me to say get an employee and then in my new system augment the data from erp with the additional data?

Comment: It depends on how you expect folks to work with the system. But, I'll say this: it's never a bad idea to have a RESTful web service fronting an app.

Comment: @JonathanM Thanks, if you want to formulate that as a formal answer I'll accept it.

Comment: someone say they're handing out Scooby Snacks??!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why re-invent parts that ERP is already covering? Sounds like you just need to augment the ERP system, not re-make it. You're basically adding fields to the `employee` table, right? Just create an aux table to hold the added fields and key it the same as the `employee` table in ERP.

As to the question of a web service, it depends on how you expect folks to work with the system. But, I'll say this: it's never a bad idea to have a RESTful web service fronting an app.